# Uniscribe and Text Outlines

Tags: truetype, glyph, uniscribe

Can I use the output from ScriptShape/ScriptItemize in Uniscribe to get the char codes and pass the char codes to GetGlyphOutline to get the beziers?

Does Uniscribe have a call to get the outlines directly?

Comment: @Downvoters. Reasons would help a lot. Or did you not get the question ? The documentation isn't the best in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering the same.

The short answer: Yes. It works.

Uniscribe returns a WORD whereas the GetCharacterPlacement one gives out an LPCSTR though, so just look at that, should be trivial.

Nothing surprising though, this was just to confirm before I spend my time on it :)

Comment: Did you manage to get it working, I am struggling with it